# help with php MVC problem

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I have groups on my site and the urls have the following hierarchy:

/ groups / {id_group} /

/ groups / {id_group} / news

/ groups / {id_group} / gallery

/ groups / {id_group} / events

/ groups / {id_group} / events / {id_event}

/ groups / {id_group} / events / {id_event} / news

/ groups / {id_group} / events / {id_event} / gallery

/ groups / {id_group} / events / {id_event} / news

As you can see a group can have news, gallery, etc. and in turn an event that is in a group can also have news, gallery, etc.

How to implement this approach in a framework without specifying any specific one?, ie I would like some guidance on what would have modules, controllers, etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All this can be achived with a simple controller , however there might be tons of variations of module/controller/action mapping , realy depends on what you need to display on the pages and how you're app is setup to work .

To get all this in one simple controller you could do the following :

```
/ groups / {id_group} /
```

Controller groups , default action

```
/ groups / {id_group} / news
```

Controller groups , news action

...

```
/ groups / {id_group} / events
```

Controller groups , events action

```
/ groups / {id_group} / events / {id_event}
```

Controller groups , specific event action. Here depending on you're framework you can either route it to a specific action , or you can test in events action if an id is sent and forward the required specific event action

...

**Edit**

if events/news/whatever , do have actions on they'r own i would have specifict events controller , specific news controller and so on , you can eaven go further and have them all separated in different modules ( for example this would allow you to have an adminNewsController , frontendNewsController with newsModel all in one place for the news module ) .

Comment: the events, news, etc. have actions (new, edit, list), where do i put those actions?

Comment: if so the i would have different controllers for each ( events , news ... ) .

Comment: thanks poelinca, i have another question, my site also have a pages section like /pages/{id_page}/events. ie, events can have different owners (pages, groups) and the actions have small variations according to the owner and also different templates.

Comment: changing layout/views depends on the framework , tough i never heard of a framework that doesn't allow you to change the view ( template ) . again depending on how different the views are you can use different css files , or different views or different layouts all together , now for different action variations acording to the owner it would be harder to setup , however you can prepare data in you're controller/model for all variations ( so you don't have duplicate code ) , then in the view display only what the owner needs tough it's not realy the best solution